# importing blogs from another database with different content type fields

Tags: migrations, database

I need to import blogs from a drupal database to another drupal database. Both the old and new drupal content types have different fields. I would like to get some hints about the sql queries or drupal api functions to be used and the process to be used to get data from old database.I have access only to the mysql database and not ftp/admin side.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the feeds module and export to a CSV file then import the data under the new respective fields. You may need to add extra fields to the new content type to prevent data loss

Comment: I have modified my question

Comment: I have access only to database

Comment: so you cannot get the feeds module installed?

Comment: I dont have admin access, so new module cant be installed

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to dump the current database on to a local drupal install that you can admin, install feeds, update your content, uninstall feeds, dump the local database then import your new local SQL dump into the restricted site